# Non-Sequential Range

Tags: vba, excel

Can I set a Range Object to be equal to a set of non-sequential cells? I want my Range to be equal to cells A1, A3, A5 etc, where I can pick and choose the rows and columns at will.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, for example this selects a fairly random set of cells:

```
Range("A1:C8,E13:G21,C20:D26,L13:N22").Select
```

and this selects the cells you mentioned:

```
Range("A1,A3,A5").Select
```

You can also combine **Range** objects with the **Union** method.

Comment: The select was simply an easy way to demonstrate visually that it works.

Answer (score 1):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174290(office.11).aspx):

Union Method

Use Union(range1, range2, ...) to return multiple-area ranges — that is, ranges composed of two or more contiguous blocks of cells. The following example creates an object defined as the union of ranges A1:B2 and C3:D4, and then selects the defined range.

```
Dim r1 As Range, r2 As Range, myMultiAreaRange As Range
Worksheets("sheet1").Activate
Set r1 = Range("A1:B2")
Set r2 = Range("C3:D4")
Set myMultiAreaRange = Union(r1, r2)
```